# Remove ~$filename.docx files from directory on unix machine

Tags: unix, directory, rm

I am trying to delete the following files from a directory of my unix machine:

```
$ ls -la
total 160
... other files ...
-rw-r--r--@   1 username  staff    171 Oct 24  2017 ~$checklist.xlsx
-rw-r--r--@   1 username  staff    171 Oct 16  2017 ~$papers.xlsx
-rw-r--r--@   1 username  staff    162 Sep  4  2017 ~$rec.docx
-rw-r--r--@   1 username  staff    162 Nov 25 21:00 ~$file1.docx
-rw-r--r--@   1 username  staff    162 Nov 25 21:01 ~$file2.docx
```

However, when I attempt to delete them, it won't let me for various reasons. For example:

```
$ rm ~$checklist.xlsx
rm: ~.xlsx: No such file or directory
$ rm $checklist.xlsx
rm: .xlsx: No such file or directory
$ rm checklist.xlsx
rm: checklist.xlsx: No such file or directory
```

Why won't my computer let me delete these files? How can I go about deleting them? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to scape those characters

a simple way to create one:

```
echo "fileteste" > \~\$file
```

a simple way to delete one:

```
rm \~\$file
```